# Debugger not starting with error TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'params'

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, python-3.x, pydev

[Using Eclipse Mars (4.5.0) on OS X 10.10.5, with PyDev 4.3.0]

I recently updated by PyDev plugin from 4.2(?) to 4.3.0 and now when I attempt to debug any of my modules, I get the following error in the Console:

```
pydev debugger: starting (pid: 9237)
Could not connect to 127.0.0.1: 63574
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_4.3.0.201508182223/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 2275, in <module>
    debugger.connect(host, port)
  File "/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_4.3.0.201508182223/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 431, in connect
    self.initializeNetwork(s)
  File "/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_4.3.0.201508182223/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 418, in initializeNetwork
    self.writer = WriterThread(sock)
  File "/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_4.3.0.201508182223/pysrc/pydevd_comm.py", line 379, in __init__
    self.cmdQueue = _queue.Queue()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'params'
```

Did I miss something on the PyDev update that I'm not doing right?  Thanks for any input here.

EDIT: To clarify, this is only a problem with the Debug configuration - the Run config for my modules work correctly. I also uninstalled and then reinstalled PyDev, but that did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had another python module `Queue` in my project, which was conflicting with `Queue` in the standard library. After renaming that, everything is working.